# Should I add an exclamation mark

Tags: punctuation

> This work pulled me more to the world of economy, and I liked every moment of it.

Should I use an exclamation mark at the end of this sentence? It is a formal letter.

Comment: It's almost impossible to say without knowing the purpose of the letter, what's in the rest of the paragraph, or what you are trying to convey emotionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a formal letter, I would avoid using the exclamation mark. The recipient can understand the meaning behind it even without the mark.

However; depending on the previous correspondence and/or familiarity, one can use it (be careful how many times you use it though). If you do not have any correspondence and/or familiarity with the recipient, simply avoid using it.

Best of luck!